# macbook keeps on freezing and restarting every hour (kernel panic)

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

This is a problem that happens to persist for 2 days now. It feels like a ticking time bomb knowing that this happens again after one hour. The error message that appears says it is a kernel panic:

```
"panic(cpu 3 caller 0xfffffe002ea90028): userspace
watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from logd 
in 120 seconds\nservice returned not alive with 
context : unresponsive dispatch queue(s): 
com.apple.firehose.io-wl \nlogd has not exited since 
first loaded"
```

I still get these kernel panics even in safe mode. This is a really chaotic situation for me as a student since I won't get things done especially online meetings knowing that my MacBook shuts down every hour.

Please advise me on what these reports say or what could possibly be causing this issue. Thank you so much!

I have attached an EtreCheck report:

```
EtreCheck Report 2023-09-25 15:17:41
EtreCheckPro version: 6.8.2 (68031)
Report generated: 2023-09-25 15:17:41
Download EtreCheckPro from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime: 1:54
Performance: Excellent

Problem: Computer is restarting

Major Issues:
  Anything that appears on this list needs immediate attention. 
  Unsigned files - There are unsigned software files installed that could be malicious and should be reviewed.
  Kernel panics - This system has experienced kernel panics. This could be a sign of hardware failure.

Minor Issues:
  These issues do not need immediate attention but they may indicate future problems or opportunities for improvement. 
  No Time Machine backup - Time Machine backup not found.
  Heavy RAM usage - Apps are using a large amount of RAM.
  Clean up - There are orphan files that could be removed.
  Unsigned files - There are unsigned software files installed. These files could be old, incompatible, and cause problems. They should be reviewed.
  System modifications - There are a large number of system modifications running in the background.
  Heavy I/O usage - Your system is under heavy I/O use. This will reduce your performance.
  Limited permissions - More information may be available with Full Disk Access.
  Kernel extensions present - This computer has kernel extensions that may not work in the future.
  Sharing enabled - This computer has sharing services enabled that could be a security risk.

Hardware Information:
  MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
    Status: Supported
  MacBook Air Model: MacBookAir10,1
  2.40 GHz Apple M1 (m1) CPU: 8-core
  16 GB RAM - Not upgradeable
  Battery: Health = Normal - Cycle count = 477

Video Information:
  Apple M1
    Color LCD (built-in) 2880 x 1800

Drives:
  disk0 - APPLE SSD AP0256Q 251.00 GB (Solid State - TRIM: Yes) 
  Internal Apple Fabric NVM Express
    disk0s1 [APFS Container] 524 MB
      disk1 [APFS Virtual drive] 524 MB (Shared by 4 volumes)
        disk1s1 - iSCPreboot (APFS) [APFS Preboot] (6 MB used)
        disk1s2 - xART (APFS) (6 MB used)
        disk1s3 - Hardware (APFS) (651 KB used)
        disk1s4 - Recovery (APFS) [Recovery] (20 KB used)
    disk0s2 [APFS Container] 245.11 GB
      disk3 [APFS Virtual drive] 245.11 GB (Shared by 6 volumes)
        disk3s1 (APFS) [APFS Container] (9.17 GB used)
          disk3s1s1 - Macintosh HD (APFS) [APFS Snapshot] (9.17 GB used)
        disk3s2 - Preboot (APFS) [APFS Preboot] (5.15 GB used)
        disk3s3 - Recovery (APFS) [Recovery] (800 MB used)
        disk3s4 - Update (APFS) (40 MB used)
        disk3s5 - Data (APFS) [APFS Virtual drive] (177.85 GB used)
        disk3s6 - VM (APFS) [APFS VM] (25 KB used)
    disk0s3 [APFS Container] 5.37 GB
      disk2 [APFS Virtual drive] 5.37 GB (Shared by 2 volumes)
        disk2s1 - Recovery (APFS) [Recovery] (1.64 GB used)
        disk2s2 - Update (APFS) (348 KB used)

Mounted Volumes:
  disk1s1 - iSCPreboot [APFS Preboot]
    Filesystem: APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/iSCPreboot
    Used: 6 MB
    Shared values
      Size: 524 MB
      Free: 506 MB

  disk1s2 - xART
    Filesystem: APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/xarts
    Used: 6 MB
    Shared values
      Size: 524 MB
      Free: 506 MB

  disk1s3 - Hardware
    Filesystem: APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/Hardware
    Used: 651 KB
    Shared values
      Size: 524 MB
      Free: 506 MB

  disk3s1s1 - Macintosh HD [APFS Snapshot]
    Filesystem: APFS
    Mount point: /
    Read-only: Yes
    Used: 9.17 GB
    Shared values
      Size: 245.11 GB
      Free: 51.96 GB
      Available: 53.20 GB

  disk3s2 - Preboot [APFS Preboot]
    Filesystem: APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/Preboot
    Used: 5.15 GB
    Shared values
      Size: 245.11 GB
      Free: 51.96 GB

  disk3s4 - Update
    Filesystem: APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/Update
    Used: 40 MB
    Shared values
      Size: 245.11 GB
      Free: 51.96 GB

  disk3s5 - Data [APFS Virtual drive]
    Filesystem: APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/Data
    Encrypted
    Used: 177.85 GB
    Shared values
      Size: 245.11 GB
      Free: 51.96 GB
      Available: 53.20 GB

  disk3s6 - VM [APFS VM]
    Filesystem: APFS
    Mount point: /System/Volumes/VM
    Used: 25 KB
    Shared values
      Size: 245.11 GB
      Free: 51.96 GB

Network:
  Interface en3: Ethernet Adapter (en3)
  Interface en4: Ethernet Adapter (en4)
  Interface en5: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
  Interface en6: Dell Universal Dock D6000
  Interface bridge0: Thunderbolt Bridge
  Interface en0: Wi-Fi
    802.11 a/b/g/n/ac/ax

  Printer sharing: Enabled
  Remote Apple Events: Enabled
  Remote Management: Enabled
  Screen sharing: Enabled
  Remote login: Enabled

System Software:
  macOS Ventura 13.6 (22G120) 
  Time since boot: Less than an hour

Notifications:
  EtreCheckPro.app
    4 notifications

  Google Chrome Helper (Alerts).app
    2 notifications

  Google Chrome.app
    3 notifications

  Creative Cloud.app
    one notification

Security:
  Gatekeeper: App Store and identified developers
  System Integrity Protection: Enabled

  Antivirus software: Apple

  Printer sharing: Enabled
  Remote Apple Events: Enabled
  Remote Management: Enabled
  Screen sharing: Enabled
  Remote login: Enabled

Unsigned Files:
  Launchd: /Library/LaunchAgents/com.amazon.sendtokindle.launcher.plist
    Executable: /usr/local/bin/stkLaunchAgent.sh
    Details: Exact match found in the legitimate list - probably OK

  Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.microsoft.OneDriveStandaloneUpdaterDaemon.plist
    Executable: /Applications/OneDrive.app/Contents/StandaloneUpdaterDaemon.xpc/Contents/MacOS/StandaloneUpdaterDaemon
    Details: Exact match found in the legitimate list - probably OK

  Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.microsoft.OneDriveUpdaterDaemon.plist
    Executable: /Applications/OneDrive.app/Contents/OneDriveUpdaterDaemon.xpc/Contents/MacOS/OneDriveUpdaterDaemon
    Details: Exact match found in the legitimate list - probably OK

  Launchd: /Library/LaunchAgents/com.microsoft.SyncReporter.plist
    Executable: /Applications/OneDrive.app/Contents/SyncReporter.app/Contents/MacOS/SyncReporter

Applications:
  520 apps
  21 x86-only apps
  4 unsigned apps

Kernel Extensions:
  /Library/Extensions
    [Not Loaded] MSMFramebuffer.kext - com.shapeservices.msm.driver.MSMFramebuffer (3.5 - SDK 10.13)
    [Not Loaded] MSMVideoDevice.kext - com.shapeservices.msm.driver.MSMVideoDevice (3.5 - SDK 10.13)

System Launch Daemons:
  [Not Loaded]  36 Apple tasks
  [Loaded]  194 Apple tasks
  [Running]  160 Apple tasks
  [Other]  One Apple task

System Launch Agents:
  [Not Loaded]  22 Apple tasks
  [Loaded]  211 Apple tasks
  [Running]  164 Apple tasks

Launch Daemons:
  [Loaded] com.adobe.ARMDC.Communicator.plist (Adobe Inc. - installed 2023-07-13)
    Executable: /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.adobe.ARMDC.Communicator

  [Loaded] com.adobe.ARMDC.SMJobBlessHelper.plist (Adobe Inc. - installed 2023-07-13)
    Executable: /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.adobe.ARMDC.SMJobBlessHelper

  [Not Loaded] com.adobe.acc.installer.v2.plist (Adobe Inc. - installed 2023-09-20)
    Executable: /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.adobe.acc.installer.v2

  [Loaded] com.iriun.cmio.DPA.camera.plist (Vesa Heikkila - installed 2022-02-26)
    Command: /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/IriunCamera.plugin/Contents/Resources/IriunAssistant 0

  [Loaded] com.iriun.cmio.DPA.camerb.plist (Vesa Heikkila - installed 2022-02-26)
    Command: /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/IriunCamera.plugin/Contents/Resources/IriunAssistant 1

  [Loaded] com.iriun.cmio.DPA.camerc.plist (Vesa Heikkila - installed 2022-02-26)
    Command: /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/IriunCamera.plugin/Contents/Resources/IriunAssistant 2

  [Loaded] com.iriun.cmio.DPA.camerd.plist (Vesa Heikkila - installed 2022-02-26)
    Command: /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/IriunCamera.plugin/Contents/Resources/IriunAssistant 3

  [Loaded] com.microsoft.OneDriveStandaloneUpdaterDaemon.plist (Not signed - installed 2021-09-24)
    Executable: /Applications/OneDrive.app/Contents/StandaloneUpdaterDaemon.xpc/Contents/MacOS/StandaloneUpdaterDaemon

  [Loaded] com.microsoft.OneDriveUpdaterDaemon.plist (Not signed - installed 2021-09-24)
    Executable: /Applications/OneDrive.app/Contents/OneDriveUpdaterDaemon.xpc/Contents/MacOS/OneDriveUpdaterDaemon

  [Loaded] com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2021-09-24)
    Executable: /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper

  [Loaded] com.microsoft.office.licensingV2.helper.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2021-09-24)
    Executable: /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.microsoft.office.licensingV2.helper

  [Loaded] us.zoom.ZoomDaemon.plist (Zoom Video Communications, Inc. - installed 2023-09-14)
    Executable: /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/us.zoom.ZoomDaemon

Launch Agents:
  [Other] com.adobe.ARMDCHelper.cc24aef4a1b90ed56a725c38014c95072f92651fb65e1bf9c8e43c37a23d420d.plist (Adobe Inc. - installed 2023-07-13)
    Executable: /Library/Application Support/Adobe/ARMDC/Application/Acrobat Update Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Acrobat Update Helper

  [Not Loaded] com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plist (Adobe Inc. - installed 2023-09-20)
    Command: /Applications/Utilities/Adobe Creative Cloud/ACC/Creative Cloud.app/Contents/MacOS/Creative Cloud --showwindow=false --onOSstartup=true

  [Not Loaded] com.adobe.ccxprocess.plist (Adobe Inc. - installed 2023-09-22)
    Command: /Applications/Utilities/Adobe Creative Cloud Experience/CCXProcess/CCXProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/CCXProcess --openAtBoot

  [Running] com.amazon.sendtokindle.launcher.plist (Not signed - installed 2021-12-19)
    Executable: /usr/local/bin/stkLaunchAgent.sh

  [Other] com.microsoft.OneDriveStandaloneUpdater.plist (Not signed - installed 2021-09-24)
    Executable: /Applications/OneDrive.app/Contents/StandaloneUpdater.app/Contents/MacOS/OneDriveStandaloneUpdater

  [Loaded] com.microsoft.SyncReporter.plist (Not signed - installed 2023-09-25)
    Executable: /Applications/OneDrive.app/Contents/SyncReporter.app/Contents/MacOS/SyncReporter

  [Other] com.microsoft.update.agent.plist (Not signed - installed 2021-09-24)
    Command: /Library/Application Support/Microsoft/MAU2.0/Microsoft AutoUpdate.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Update Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Update Assistant --launchByAgent

User Launch Agents:
  [Running] com.google.keystone.agent.plist (Google LLC - installed 2022-10-27)
    Command: ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent -runMode ifneeded

  [Running] com.google.keystone.xpcservice.plist (Google LLC - installed 2022-10-27)
    Command: ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent -runMode xpchost

User Login Items:
  [Not Loaded] Bitwarden Login Helper (App Store - installed 2023-09-24)
    Modern Login Item
    /Applications/Bitwarden.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/Bitwarden Login Helper.app

  [Loaded] HPPSDrMonitorHelper (App Store - installed 2023-09-24)
    Modern Login Item
    /Applications/HP Smart.app/Contents/Frameworks/HPDiagnosticKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Addons/HP Diagnose & Fix.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/HPPSDrMonitorHelper.app

  [Not Loaded] JumpcutHelper (Steve COOK - installed 2021-07-02)
    Modern Login Item
    /Applications/Jumpcut.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/JumpcutHelper.app

  [Loaded] RectangleLauncher (Ryan Hanson - installed 2021-07-04)
    Modern Login Item
    /Applications/Rectangle.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/RectangleLauncher.app

  [Not Loaded] StartUpHelper (Spotify - installed 2022-01-07)
    Modern Login Item
    /Applications/Spotify.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/StartUpHelper.app

App Extensions:
  Safari extensions:
    Bitwarden - /Applications/Bitwarden.app

  File providers:
    SHAREit - /Applications/SHAREit.app

  Share services:
    Telegram - /Applications/Telegram.app

  Finder sync extensions:
    Adobe Content Synchronizer Finder Extension - /Applications/Utilities/Adobe Sync/CoreSync/Core Sync.app

  Action services:
    SHAREit - /Applications/SHAREit.app

  QuickLook Previews:
    EtreCheckQuickLook - ~/Downloads/EtreCheckPro.app
      com.etresoft.etrecheck4 *.etrecheck

  QuickLook Previews (legacy):
    BlackmagicRaw - /Applications/Blackmagic RAW/Blackmagic RAW Player.app
      com.blackmagic-design.braw-movie *.braw

Internet Plug-ins:
  AdobePDFViewer: 21.005.20058 (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2021-06-27)
  AdobePDFViewerNPAPI: 17.012.20098 (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2021-06-27)

Audio Plug-ins:
  BlackHole2ch: 0.2.10 (Existential Audio Inc. - installed 2021-08-08)
  ZoomAudioDevice: 1.0 (Zoom Video Communications, Inc. - installed 2022-03-25)
  IriunMic: 1.3 (Iriun Oy - installed 2022-02-26)

CoreMediaIO Plug-ins:
  IriunCamera: 1.5 (Vesa Heikkila - installed 2022-02-26)
  obs-mac-virtualcam: 27.0.1 (Wizards of OBS LLC - installed 2021-08-24)

Backup:
  Time Machine Not Configured!

Performance:
  System Load: 1.86 (1 min ago) 3.30 (5 min ago) 2.71 (15 min ago)
  Nominal I/O usage: 46.07 MB/s
  File system: 8.75 seconds
  Write speed: 1105 MB/s
  Read speed: 2705 MB/s

CPU Usage Snapshot:
  Type Overall
  System: 4 %
  User: 3 %
  Idle: 93 %

Top Processes Snapshot by CPU:
  Process (count) CPU (Source - Location)
  kernel_task 17.20 % (Apple)
  EtreCheckPro 14.42 % (Etresoft, Inc.)
  WindowServer 10.96 % (Apple)
  mds 8.36 % (Apple)
  mdbulkimport 4.12 % (Apple)

Top Processes Snapshot by Memory:
  Process (count) RAM usage (Source - Location)
  Google Chrome Helper (Renderer) (23) 3.95 GB (Google LLC)
  EtreCheckPro 1.04 GB (Etresoft, Inc.)
  Google Chrome 553 MB (Google LLC)
  System Settings 322 MB (Apple)
  Finder 242 MB (Apple)

Top Processes Snapshot by Network Use:
  Process (count) Input / Output (Source - Location)
  mDNSResponder 545 KB / 517 KB (Apple)
  rapportd 15 KB / 35 KB (Apple)
  apsd 12 KB / 25 KB (Apple)
  parsecd 6 KB / 2 KB (Apple)
  netbiosd 3 KB / 2 KB (Apple)

Top Processes Snapshot by Energy Use:
  Process (count) Energy (0-100) (Source - Location)
  WindowServer 5 (Apple)
  spindump 1 (Apple)
  Google Chrome Helper (Renderer) (23) 1 (Google LLC)
  Google Chrome 0 (Google LLC)
  GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent (2) 0 (Google LLC)

Virtual Memory Information:
  Physical RAM: 16 GB

  Free RAM: 1.45 GB
  Used RAM: 9.13 GB
  Cached files: 5.42 GB

  Available RAM: 6.87 GB
  Swap Used: 0 B

Software Installs (past 60 days):
  Install Date Name (Version)
  2023-08-10 Adobe Acrobat (23.003.20269) (23.003.20269)
  2023-08-10 Goodnotes (6.0.1)
  2023-08-24 Adobe Acrobat (23.003.20284) (23.003.20284)
  2023-09-02 Xmind (23.8.2122)
  2023-09-02 Talk To AI (1.0)
  2023-09-02 EasyChat (1.6.0)
  2023-09-02 Chatty (1.1.2)
  2023-09-02 Python (0)
  2023-09-14 Zoom (5.15.7.21404)
  2023-09-14 Adobe Acrobat (23.006.20320) (23.006.20320)
  2023-09-16 XProtectPlistConfigData (2171)
  2023-09-16 XProtectPayloads (111)
  2023-09-24 Bitwarden (2023.8.4)
  2023-09-24 HP Smart (16.5.1)
  2023-09-24 macOS 13.6 (13.6)
  2023-09-24 RosettaUpdateAuto (1.0.0.0.1.1694861547)
  2023-09-25 Microsoft OneDrive (23.189.910)

Clean up:
  /Library/LaunchAgents/com.microsoft.OneDriveStandaloneUpdater.plist
    /Applications/OneDrive.app/Contents/StandaloneUpdater.app/Contents/MacOS/OneDriveStandaloneUpdater
    Executable not found
  /Library/LaunchAgents/com.microsoft.update.agent.plist
    /Library/Application Support/Microsoft/MAU2.0/Microsoft AutoUpdate.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Update Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Update Assistant
    Executable not found

Diagnostics Information (past 7-30 days):
  2023-09-25 15:07:22 Kernel Panic (8 times)
    Details:
      panic(cpu 3 caller 0xfffffe0014f8c028): userspace watchdog timeout: no
       successful checkins from logd in 120 seconds
      Panicked task 0xfffffe1b3f0ca738: 353 pages, 4 threads: pid 135: watch
      dogd


  2023-09-23 09:57:49 mds_stores High CPU Use
    Executable: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mds_stores

  2023-09-20 09:31:03 photolibraryd High CPU Use
    Executable: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/photolibraryd


End of report
```

Comment: If you read the report, it will telll you that you have a ton of unsigned files.  Given that OneDrive is included here, I would wipe your MacBook and do a fresh, clean install of the tools you need - don't use Migration Assistant.  But even before that, once it has a clean install, see if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

The Etrecheck report shows you've got a ton of crap installed, any one of which could be causing the problem.

Notably, the MSM Kernel extensions, and Bitwarden.

Your One Drive drivers are quite old: check for new versions.

I thought Internet plug-ins were a thing of a past!

Audio drivers can also be a common source of problems, if they're not well-written and up to date.

However, SafeBoot mode usually disables third-party extensions, drivers etc, so that's odd.

You could try a brand new user account, and see if the problem occurs there. That will rule out the OS and hardware, if the problem goes away.

But you will need to do some detective work to narrow down the source of the problem.

At the worst, you can Erase All User Content in System Settings. (you don't need to wipe the entire disk and reinstall the OS anymore). If it still panics, then it's likely a hardware issue.

If you can get to an Apple Store for an appointment, they can at least rule out hardware (or not) fairly easily.